What is the path to define in application.properties in quarkus native image?
I have my quarkus (version 3.9) app that uses quarkus-google-cloud-firebase-admin plugin (version 2.11.0). I defined my Google credentials in a file called application_default_credentials.json and (following the guide lines) I defined quarkus.google.cloud.service-account-location property in application.property in this way:
quarkus.google.cloud.service-account-location=src\\main\\resources\\application_default_credentials.json

In my local machine (with dev profile) all works fine. In production I get this error:
2024-09-05 15:15:45 2024-09-05 13:15:45,022 DEBUG [io.ver.ext.web.RoutingContext] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-3) RoutingContext failure (500): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error injecting com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth io.quarkiverse.googlecloudservices.firebase.admin.runtime.authentication.http.DefaultFirebaseIdentityProvider.auth
2024-09-05 15:15:45     at io.quarkiverse.googlecloudservices.firebase.admin.runtime.authentication.http.DefaultFirebaseIdentityProvider_Bean.doCreate(Unknown Source)
2024-09-05 15:15:45     ... 69 more
2024-09-05 15:15:45 Caused by: jakarta.enterprise.inject.CreationException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: src/main/resources/application_default_credentials.json (No such file or directory)
2024-09-05 15:15:45     at io.quarkiverse.googlecloudservices.common.GcpCredentialProducer_ProducerMethod_googleCredential_ZtOjNbKgWzVHMIt1D1Qv1hwSeRY_Bean.create(Unknown Source)
2024-09-05 15:15:45     at io.quarkiverse.googlecloudservices.common.GcpCredentialProducer_ProducerMethod_googleCredential_ZtOjNbKgWzVHMIt1D1Qv1hwSeRY_Bean.create(Unknown Source)
2024-09-05 15:15:45     at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext.createInstanceHandle(AbstractSharedContext.java:119)
2024-09-05 15:15:45     at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext$1.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:38)
2024-09-05 15:15:45     at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext$1.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:35)
2024-09-05 15:15:45     at io.quarkus.arc.impl.LazyValue.get(LazyValue.java:32)
2024-09-05 15:15:45     at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ComputingCache.computeIfAbsent(ComputingCache.java:69)
2024-09-05 15:15:45     at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ComputingCacheContextInstances.computeIfAbsent(ComputingCacheContextInstances.java:19)
2024-09-05 15:15:45     at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:35)
2024-09-05 15:15:45     at io.quarkiverse.googlecloudservices.common.GcpCredentialProducer_ProducerMethod_googleCredential_ZtOjNbKgWzVHMIt1D1Qv1hwSeRY_Bean.get(Unknown Source)
2024-09-05 15:15:45     at io.quarkiverse.googlecloudservices.common.GcpCredentialProducer_ProducerMethod_googleCredential_ZtOjNbKgWzVHMIt1D1Qv1hwSeRY_Bean.get(Unknown Source)
2024-09-05 15:15:45     ... 93 more
2024-09-05 15:15:45 Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: src/main/resources/application_default_credentials.json (No such file or directory)
2024-09-05 15:15:45     at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
2024-09-05 15:15:45     at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:213)
2024-09-05 15:15:45     at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:152)
2024-09-05 15:15:45     at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:106)
2024-09-05 15:15:45     at io.quarkiverse.googlecloudservices.common.GcpCredentialProducer.googleCredential(GcpCredentialProducer.java:48)
2024-09-05 15:15:45     at io.quarkiverse.googlecloudservices.common.GcpCredentialProducer_ProducerMethod_googleCredential_ZtOjNbKgWzVHMIt1D1Qv1hwSeRY_Bean.doCreate(Unknown Source)
2024-09-05 15:15:45     ... 104 more

I use the default Quarkus native Dockerfile:
    FROM maven:3.9.6-eclipse-temurin-21-alpine AS builder
    RUN mkdir /build
    ADD . /build/
    
    WORKDIR /build
    RUN mvn package
    
    FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/openjdk-21:1.18
    
    ENV LANG='en_US.UTF-8' LANGUAGE='en_US:en'
    
    # We make four distinct layers so if there are application changes the library layers can be re-used
    COPY --from=builder --chown=185 /build/target/quarkus-app/lib/ /car/lib/
    COPY --from=builder --chown=185 /build/target/quarkus-app/*.jar /car/
    COPY --from=builder --chown=185 /build/target/quarkus-app/app/ /car/app/
    COPY --from=builder --chown=185 /build/target/quarkus-app/quarkus/ /car/quarkus/
    
    EXPOSE 8080:8080
    USER 185
    ENV AB_JOLOKIA_OFF=""
    ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0 -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"
    ENV JAVA_OPTS_APPEND="-Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0 -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"
    ENV JAVA_APP_JAR="/car/quarkus-run.jar"
    
    ENTRYPOINT [ "/opt/jboss/container/java/run/run-java.sh" ]

In docker machine I have:

And the .jar file is:

So, the problem is java.io.FileNotFoundException: src/main/resources/application_default_credentials.json (No such file or directory). Why in dev all works fine and in prod not? What is the right path to use in application.properties?

It depends on what the extensions expects quarkus.google.cloud.service-account-location to be - a file on the file system or a classpath resource
